# How do I play 2 videos in HTML5 back to back

Tags: video, html, html5-video

I wish to use html5 to play 2 different videos back to back. Is there a way to do this within the html5 or do I have to take a javascript route & if so can anyone make any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: The HTML5 spec doesn't allow for this, but if you take the javascript route, beware that some mobile devices may require user action to play media.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the HTML5 spec allows this.  Multiple source files can be specified so the browser can pick which video file format it supports and play only one of them.

```
<video height="270" width="480" controls>
  <source src="/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/myvideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <a href="/myvideo.mp4">Download the video</a> for local playback.
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave - I tried this before posting the question on the off chance that it might work but it doesn't do what I want. I guess I'll have to find a nice javascript solution - thanks anyway